# Does linq return the whole datasource or just the select column specified?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

Given queries like this:

```
var myThingy =>
         (from rg in _repository.GetQueryable<TheThing>()
          where rg.Id == someId
          select rg);

var myThingysId =>
         (from rg in _repository.GetQueryable<TheThing>()
          where rg.Id == someId
          select rg.Id);
```

In the first one I'm asking for a full TheThingy and in the second one, only its Id.

What I want to know is will they both produce the same SQL query?

Comment: Almost always a better idea to get a profiler at this stage and see *what SQL is being sent* rather than having to ask questions about each query pattern you may be curious about.

Comment: I know. Just thought I could skip that if someone knew already... :-(

Comment: I could make an educated guess but it's a log time since I looked at LINQ to SQL. Are you sure you're not using e.g. Entity Framework?

Comment: No I'm not I'm using nhibernate actually.

Answer (score 3):

Linq returns whole data source (all columns) in first case -

Linq code:

```
from t in Persons select t
```

Generated SQL:

```
 SELECT [t0].[PersonID], [t0].[FirstName], [t0].[LastName] FROM [Person] AS [t0]
```

And returns only specified columns in second case -

Linq Code:

```
from t in Persons select new {t.PersonID}
```

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT [t0].[PersonID] FROM [Person] AS [t0]
```

Answer (score 3):

No. Generate different queries. Because, tries to produce the query with the best performance.

View all queries that it creates. Simple example:

```
var sqlQuery = ((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<YouEntityType>)YouQuery).Sql;

Console.WriteLine("work query: "+sqlQuery);
```

My Example Screenshot

[image]